# MVC HTML Compress filter exception when using html.action in view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Code taken from [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/845874/HTTP-Respond-Content-Compression-with-MVC-Controll).

When using **Html.action** in **main view** to render a **partial view** it gives me value cannot be null exception on response.Filter.

## Filter

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new CompressAttribute());
    }
}

public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

        encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
}
```

## View

```
<div>
   @Html.Action("GetAccountCompanies", "Account")
</div>
```

## Action

```
[HttpGet]
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult GetAccountCompanies()
{
     return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_AccountCompanies.cshtml");
}
```

## Exception

```
response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
```

> Response.Filter = Value cannot be null

Filter works when I comment out

```
@Html.Action("GetAccountCompanies", "Account")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CompressAttribute is called for each action so we need to make sure we don't compress childactions, (response.filter == null)

```
public class CompressAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (response.Filter != null)
        {
            var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

            encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();

            if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```